# How to Deal with SET ANSI_NULLS ON or OFF?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to call this procedure that sends one value that can be NULL or any int value.

```
SELECT DomainName, DomainCode FROM Tags.tblDomain WHERE SubDomainId =@SubDomainId
```

I simply want to use this single query rather than what i m doing right now in below given code.

I searched for this how could i do this then i got [this Link](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13062).

According to this I have to set ANSI_NULLS OFF

I am not able to set this inside this procedure before executing my sql query and then reset it again after doing this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Tags].[spOnlineTest_SubDomainSelect] 
    @SubDomainId INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF @SubDomainId IS NULL
        SELECT DomainName, DomainCode FROM Tags.tblDomain WHERE SubDomainId IS NULL 
    ELSE
        SELECT DomainName, DomainCode FROM Tags.tblDomain WHERE SubDomainId =@SubDomainId
END
```

What will be the better practice to do deal with ANSI_NULLS or Using If Else

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SET ANSI_NULLS is ony defined at stored proc create time and cannot be set at run time.

[From CREATE PROC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

> Using SET Options
>
> The Database Engine saves the settings
>   of both SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER and SET
>   ANSI_NULLS when a Transact-SQL stored
>   procedure is created or modified.
>   These original settings are used when
>   the stored procedure is executed.
>   Therefore, any client session settings
>   for SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER and SET
>   ANSI_NULLS are ignored when the stored
>   procedure is running. Other SET
>   options, such as SET ARITHABORT, SET
>   ANSI_WARNINGS, or SET ANSI_PADDINGS
>   are not saved when a stored procedure
>   is created or modified. If the logic
>   of the stored procedure depends on a
>   particular setting, include a SET
>   statement at the start of the
>   procedure to guarantee the appropriate
>   setting. When a SET statement is
>   executed from a stored procedure, the
>   setting remains in effect only until
>   the stored procedure has finished
>   running. The setting is then restored
>   to the value the stored procedure had
>   when it was called. This enables
>   individual clients to set the options
>   they want without affecting the logic
>   of the stored procedure.

The same applies to [`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx)

In this case, use IF ELSE because [SET ANSI_NULLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) will be **ON** in the future.

Or Peter Lang's suggestion.

To be honest, expecting `SubDomainId = @SubDomainId` to work when @SubDomainId is NULL is not really correct usage of NULL...

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use a single query?

```
SELECT DomainName, DomainCode
FROM Tags.tblDomain
WHERE ( @SubDomainId IS NULL AND SubDomainId IS NULL )
   OR ( SubDomainId = @SubDomainId )
```

Comment: @Peter Lang: thx for solution, presently i will workout from ur solution. But Question is still open for ANSI_NULLS also.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I'm pretty sure ...

```
ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

Applies to the procedure when you create/edit it, it's like a setting of the procedure.

So either the procedure has it ON or OFF. Your example was a query not a procedure so I'm a little confused.

But if you have SQL 2005/2008 for example if you "edit" procedure it opens up your procedure in a new tab you'll see the ANSI_NULLS OFF near the top.

You can edit it there and set it ON or OFF and update it to change ...

Comment: Note, you can use that setting in a query too ... I'm just saying how it works with a procedure.

Comment: I am trying to use it with query. I is working fine for procedure i.e. if i do it OFF on procedure. But i want to make it OFF only for Query. Any Suggestion ?